# selecting alpha for a color to be layered for largest gamut

Tags: javascript, colors, color-space

**a** is the alpha value for a grayscale color:
`rgba(0,0,0,a)`

I want to stack this color up to **z** times on a white rgb background.

*Given **z**, how do I determine what **a** will create the widest gamut of resulting grayscale values?*

I naively thought that I could solve with 255/z, but this results in my darkest grayscale values nowhere near 255.  Here are three layers (z = 3), where I set a = 85.  Alas!  The darkest it gets is 180, so I could have increased `a` and ended up with a wider gamut.  But how?

[image: three layered rectangles]

https://codepen.io/jedierikb/pen/JjRebjB?editors=1010

```
const $c = document.getElementById( 'c' );
$c.width = 200;
$c.height = 200;

const ctx = $c.getContext( '2d' );
const numLayers = 3;

const alpha = Math.round(255/numLayers);
ctx.fillStyle = '#000000' + intToHex(  alpha );
for (var i=0; i<numLayers; ++i) {
  ctx.fillRect( i*10, i*10, 100, 100 );
}

//let's get a pixel
var id = ctx.getImageData(numLayers*10, numLayers*10, 1, 1).data;
console.log( 'for ' + numLayers + ' layers, using alpha ' + alpha );
console.log( 'resulting in darkest alpha being', id[3] );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example (both the image and the CodePen) the alpha is `0.33`.

The lightest color is `170`, which is `67%` of `255`. So the first layer of black removed a measure of brightness equal to its alpha (`0.33 = 33%`).

Now, when the second layer is applied, the brigthness is substracted not from white but from the first layer. It had a brightness of 67%, so the second layer has a brightness of `67% * (1 - 0.33) = ~44%`, which in RGB is `255 * 44% = ~112`, equal to the color of the second layer.

The third layer will have a brightness of `44% * (1 - 0.33) = ~30%`, which in RGB is `255 * 30% = ~75`, equal to the color of the third layer.

Therefore, if you're applying black with alpha `a` to a white background `z` times, the `z`-th color will be

`255 * (1 - a)^z`

The range of values can be calculated using:

`range = 255 * (1 - a) - 255 * (1 - a)^z`

`first color - last color`

By graphing this function you can tell that, for example, for `z = 3` the local maximum is at `0.4226`. You can also solve the polynomial or just cheat, calculate the value for `a` in increments of `0.05` and pick the highest result.

```js
function greatestGamutAlpha(layers, precision = 5) {
    let maxRangeAlpha,
        maxRange = 0;
    for (let a = 0; a < 100; a += precision) {
        const alpha = a / 100,
            range = 255 * (1 - alpha) - 255 * (1 - alpha) ** layers;
        if (range > maxRange) {
            maxRange = range;
            maxRangeAlpha = alpha;
        }
    }
    return maxRangeAlpha;
}
```